# How to get at columns in jagged array without LINQ C#

Tags: c#, jagged-arrays

I have a jagged array with all rows the same size.

```
string[][] myArray = new string[4][];
        myArray[0] = new string[4];
        myArray[1] = new string[4];
        myArray[2] = new string[4];
        myArray[3] = new string[4];
```

And values initialized

```
for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
            {
                string blah = Console.ReadLine ();
                myArray [k] = blah.Select (c => c.ToString ()).ToArray ();
            }
```

Once created, I could check a row for a particular sequence

```
if (string.Join("", myArray[0]) == "TXXX")
    //do something
```

But since the rows are created as separate objects, there doesn't seem to be way to refer to a column. What I'm trying to achieve once the jagged array is filled, is to check rows and columns for particular string sequences.

I tried with a 2-D array but it seemed clumsy to refer to rows or columns easily. A jagged array seemed more logical to me to set up because the rows were to easy to call.

Comment: The 2D array makes it equally easy (or 'clumsy' depending on your perspective) to access rows or columns. Making one direction easier at the expense of the other doesn't help.  BTW why do you say "without LINQ" but use `Select` in your code?

Comment: It looks like your code is working. What are you asking? I don't see the question.